# Differential Equation problem about variation of Euler Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x^3 y''' - 3 x^2 y'' + x(6 - x^2) y' - (6 - x^2) y = 0$$

I am wondering how to deal with this kind of DE, when there is extra terms in the normal Euler equation.

Thank you guys

Comment: **Hint:** One approach could be to let $y = v x \implies y' = v + v' x$, substitute and solve.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=xu$ ,

Then $y'=xu'+u$

$y''=xu''+u'+u'=xu''+2u'$

$y'''=xu'''+u''+2u''=xu'''+3u''$

$\therefore x^3(xu'''+3u'')-3x^2(xu''+2u')+x(6-x^2)(xu'+u)-(6-x^2)xu=0$

$x^4u'''+3x^3u''-3x^3u''-6x^2u'+x^2(6-x^2)u'+x(6-x^2)u-(6-x^2)xu=0$

$x^4u'''-x^4u'=0$

$u'''-u'=0$

$u=C_1e^x+C_2e^{-x}+C_3$

$\therefore y=C_1xe^x+C_2xe^{-x}+C_3x$